# Mysql/PHP Select in one query the rows that exists in Table1 or in Table2

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I hope you can help me: I'm developing in php/mysql and get stucked in this sql problem. I have 3 tables with some fields: Table1, Table2 and Table3.Let put en example:

Tables/Fields
Table1.Id 
Table2.Id
Table3.Id

So, I need in one query (SELECT) to get the rows in Table1 that exists in Table2 or in Table3. Actually, I'm getting the row in two querys and mix it (Table1.id=Table2.id)(Table1.id=Table3.id)

Answer (score 3):

Might be better with subqueries

```
    select *
    from Table1 t1
    where t1.id in (select t2.id from Table2 t2)
    or t1.id in (select t3.id from Table3 t3)
```

Or

```
select *
        from Table1 t1
        where t1.id in 
       (select t2.id from Table2 t2
       union
       select t3.id from Table3 t3)
```

Comment: Cool, thanks Mateo, your solution works fine. I appreciate.

Answer (score 1):

```
select  * from table1
inner join  
table2
on table1.id=table2.id
union
select  * from table1
inner join  
table3
on table1.id=table3.id
```